# One more step before you're done - stripe checkout payment issue

Tags: asp.net-core, stripe-payments

We are currently in the process of integrating Stripe payment for one of our clients. Our chosen method for payment integration is Stripe Checkout. The client has created a Stripe account and provided us with the necessary details, including the Publishable Key, Secret Key, and signing secret key.

Initially, we conducted tests using the "test mode" and everything worked as expected. However, when we switched to the "live" mode and updated the configuration with the appropriate keys, we encountered an issue during our live payment tests. We are unable to proceed with the payment as we are consistently presented with a "One more step before you're done" popup message.
[image: One more step before you're done]
We would greatly appreciate your guidance and steps to resolve the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with the popup? There's not really enough for us to go on here. This also sounds like a better question for Stripe's Support team.

Comment: Included screenshot

Comment: This seems like a captcha issue not a code-related one, I'd recommend chatting with Stripe's support team instead: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Seems captcha pics were blocked by firewall